# Программа нормально отрабатывает под netbeаns, но ехе выдает ошибку

Tags: c++

Ошибка при запуске приложения (0xc000007b).

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "utf-8");
    string fin;
    int R;
    cout << "введите сумму " << endl;
    cin >> R;
    if(R%100 >= 11 && R%100 <= 19)
    {
            fin = "рублей";
    }
    else
    {
        switch(R%10)
        {
            case 1:
                fin = "рубль";
                break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                fin = "рубля";
                break;
            default:
                fin = "рублей";
        }
    }
    cout << "У вас " << R << " " << fin << "!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо всем откликнувшимся!
Итак проблема была в Cygwin64.
После установки и настройки MinGv все начало запускаться ссылка по настройке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224381/mingw-netbeans-6-9-1-problem

единственное что бесить МинГв не хочет отображаться в выводе нетбинс

Comment: C:\it\C++\Rub\dist\Release\Cygwin-Windows если это важно

Comment: С программой все в порядке. А зачем вы ее под Cygwin собираете? Собирайте под MinGW.

Comment: Под Администратором пробовали запустить?

Comment: @gbg Собираю через ф11 (молоток точнее) или запустить проект не владею как иначе. Плагины довешивал к php сборке.

Comment: @DimXenon проверил без изменений. Попробовал режим совместимости тоже результата не дало.

Comment: Тогда и правда - попробуйте собрать, например, в MS студии Express Edition (https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs) или ещё в чём-то менее "экзотичном".

Comment: Полагаю, в системе просто нет рантаймовых библиотек system-wide. А при запуске из среды они лежат где-то неподалёку и подхватываются.

Answer (score 2):

Исходный код ошибок не содержит. Попробуйте собирать в менее экзотической для C++ среде нормальным компилятором

[Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/ru/download-open-source/)

[Microsoft Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибок, похоже, нет, но вот этот набор:

```
using namespace std;

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
```

явно содержит лишнее. Уберите или первую строчку, или следующие три. Лучше следующие три, потому что

```
using std::string;
```

вы не написали (кстати, и не включили заголовочный файл `string`; например, VC++ на это ругается...)